# emacs ruby mode: can I reorder methods in file (alphabetical order)

Tags: sorting, ruby-mode

After opening the file

```
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
```

Which has

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def foo
     puts "foo"
   end

   def baa
     puts "baa"
   end

end
```

I want to add a function/method to this file, but before that
I would like to tell emacs to reorder things so that `def foo`
comes *after* `def baa` because of alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking the region and calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sort-paragraphs` <kbd>RET</kbd> should do it

sort-paragraphs is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
‘sort.el’.

(sort-paragraphs REVERSE BEG END)

Sort paragraphs in region alphabetically; argument means descending order.
Called from a program, there are three arguments:
REVERSE (non-nil means reverse order), BEG and END (region to sort).
The variable ‘sort-fold-case’ determines whether alphabetic case affects
the sort order.